# pytorch LSTM to map series of feature vectors to their labels

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, lstm

currently I have input X with shape (50, 25), where there are 50 feature vectors and each vector has 25 dimensions. The data of X is, for example, like follows:

```
X = [[0. 0. 0. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 1. 1. 1.]]
```

And the output label y is `[0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]`, of length 50. I.e. each feature vector has a label which corresponds to an element in y.

how can I construct a pytorch LSTM, reshape the input object to 3 dimensions, and properly interpret the output object? Thanks so much for the help in advance.

Currently I have a template for LSTM like this, since my input is already numerical, I was thinking to get rid of the encoder / decoder part, is that correct?

```
class RNNModel(nn.Module):
    """Container module with an encoder, a recurrent module, and a decoder."""

    def __init__(self, rnn_type, ntoken, ninp, nhid, nlayers, dropout=0, tie_weights=False):
        super(RNNModel, self).__init__()
        self.drop = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.ntoken = ntoken 
        self.decoder = nn.Linear(nhid, self.ntoken)
        if rnn_type in ['LSTM', 'GRU']:
            self.rnn = getattr(nn, rnn_type)(ninp, nhid, nlayers, dropout=dropout)
        else:
            try:
                nonlinearity = {'RNN_TANH': 'tanh', 'RNN_RELU': 'relu'}[rnn_type]
            except KeyError:
                raise ValueError( """An invalid option for `--model` was supplied,
                                 options are ['LSTM', 'GRU', 'RNN_TANH' or 'RNN_RELU']""")
            self.rnn = nn.RNN(ninp, nhid, nlayers, nonlinearity=nonlinearity, dropout=dropout)

        self.init_weights()

        self.rnn_type = rnn_type
        self.nhid = nhid
        self.nlayers = nlayers

    def init_weights(self):
        initrange = 0.1
        nn.init.zeros_(self.decoder.weight)
        nn.init.uniform_(self.decoder.weight, -initrange, initrange)

    def forward(self, input, hidden):
        emb = self.drop(input)
        emb = emb.transpose(1, 0)

        output, hidden = self.rnn(emb, hidden) #output of shape (length, batchsize, nhid)
        output = self.drop(output)
        output = output[-1, :, :] #shape (batchsize, nhid)

        decoded = self.decoder(output) #shape (batchsize, ntoken)
        return F.log_softmax(decoded, dim=1), hidden 

    def init_hidden(self, bsz):
        weight = next(self.parameters())
        if self.rnn_type == 'LSTM':
            return (weight.new_zeros(self.nlayers, bsz, self.nhid),
                    weight.new_zeros(self.nlayers, bsz, self.nhid))
        else:
            return weight.new_zeros(self.nlayers, bsz, self.nhid)
```

Currently the train I wrote is

```
X = X.reshape((1, 50, 25))
hidden = self.model.init_hidden(1)
for iter in range(0, self.epochs):
    data = torch.from_numpy(X)
    target = torch.LongTensor(y.reshape((1, torch.LongTensor(y).size(0))))
    self.model.zero_grad()
    self.optimizer.zero_grad()
    hidden = self.repackage_hidden(hidden)
  
    output, hidden = self.model(data.float(), hidden)   
    loss = self.criterion(output, target)
    loss.backward() 
    torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(self.model.parameters(), 0.25) 
    self.optimizer.step()
    self.model.train()
```

But I got the error: `RuntimeError: multi-target not supported at /tmp/pip-req-build-4baxydiv/aten/src/THNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.c:22`

Answer (score 0):

Output of rnn take shape of (length, batchsize, nhid), base on your label (1 number per sample) I assume you're doing classification, so usually we will give the classifier (self.decoder) output features of the last timestep. Here I changed your forward method to this and got output of shape (batchsize, ntoken) which fit the shape of your label.

```
def forward(self, input, hidden):
    emb = self.drop(self.encoder(input))
    emb = emb.transpose(1, 0) #(batchsize, length, ninp) => (length, batchsize, ninp)

    output, hidden = self.rnn(emb, hidden) #output of shape (length, batchsize, nhid)
    output = self.drop(output)
    output = output[-1, :, :] #shape (batchsize, nhid)

    decoded = self.decoder(output) #shape (batchsize, ntoken)
    return F.log_softmax(decoded, dim=1), hidden
```

About getting rid of self.encoder, it is a embedding layer which take a array of indices and replace each of them with a vector. If your input includes indices (int/long) of something, you may use it, otherwise (it is not index but some number as float like temperature,...) you should get rid of it (because it's wrong). Sorry if my English is confusing.

Comment: Thank you! And do you know how I can transform my 2D feature vector to a 3D one? What should be the value for each dimension? Here I think ninp would be 25, and length would be 50, but what should the batch size be? I am also confused about how I can make my target (i.e. y) reshaping to the correct size so that I can use `loss = self.criterion(output, target)`

Comment: Oh, maybe I misunderstand your question, does X in your question is a sample or each row of it is a sample (I thought each row of it is a sample) ? Can you tell me what problem you're trying to solve ? By batch size, I mean number of samples you give to your data. About how to add a dimension to your data, you may use X.unsqueeze(dim) with dim is where you want to add it, for example X.unsqueeze(dim=1) may change X from (50, 25) to (50, 1, 25).

Comment: Yeah, each row of it is a sample, if I understand correctly. Basically I just want to train the model, and finally input a feature vector (a sample) to the model and get the label. I'm confused by how to write the train function for the LSTM, what should the input shape be (transformed from X), and what should the target shape be (transformed from y). I upload the code above, can you take a look? Thanks!

Comment: If you use embedding layer (like your template), you don't need to change anything, it will turn your input tensor to (batchsize, length, ninp) which in this case (50, 25, ninp), then you need to change it to (length, batchsize, ninp) using transpose (just convention of torch, you can look up documentation for it) before put it to rnn. If you don't use embedding layer and you want to put exactly value of X to the rnn then use method unsqueeze(-1) to turn X to (50, 25, 1) then transpose(0, 1) to (25, 50, 1) (50 samples, each one has 25 timesteps, each timestep is represented with single number)

Comment: Actually, the feature vector only corresponds to one time step, and each dimension of the feature vector corresponds to one feature, there are 25 features in total for this timestep. In this case what should the formulation be? Sorry for the confusion, I'm very new to NN and machine learning, and thanks for the thoughtful answer!

Comment: So X is a sample and it has 50 timestep, each timestep is a vector with size 25, then input will be shape (50, 1, 25) for (length, batchsize, n_features). Use X.unsqueeze(1) to turn X to that shape. Also, the code in my answer is wrong then. Your problem is similar to a "sequence to sequence problem", you may want to use that keyword to research further.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been searching for a while but not sure where to proceed, could you point me to possibly some materials? I've been looking at https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/seq2seq_translation_tutorial.html#evaluation, but the problem formulation is somewhat different